# 2D CAD canvas implementation

Tags: c#, canvas, 2d, cad

I want to develop a C# basedsimple interactive 2D cad canvas to display simple objects like lines, arc, text. I want to perform object selection and editing too.

I want to evaluate options since it is the beginning stage. I did considerable amount of survey and still I am open to new ideas. Some of my founding are

1. Using OpenGL C# libraries (OpenTK, SharpGL) [but OpenTK is abandoned I guess]
2. Having an user control and implement all the functionality manually such as object selections, object addition and all, but work load is very high in this case.

Could you please let me know if there are any other option? Please give some hints then I can make a right decision

Comment: possible duplicate of [CAD application by using opengl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050214/cad-application-by-using-opengl)

Answer (score 1):

WPF/Silverlight are also very suitable.
Take a look for my experience at post [2D CAD WPF Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167654/2d-cad-application-in-wpf/17056012#17056012) especially at hi end interactivity level.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed by using OpenTK. It provide enough supports for my own CAD development such as selection, font support. Even though OpenTK development stopped in 2010, some people are continuously maintaining the source in Git.

There is a 100 page PDF manual with the installation it helps a lot. In addition to that please look the respective sample code in the installation directory